# How do I retrieve an average from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to get the average value of a selection of a column. I'm trying to use SQL's AVG(X) function, but am not sure how. Here's what I've tried, but I get a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException when calling `c.getDouble(0)`. How should I do this?

```
    String q = "SELECT AVG(" + KEY_PERCENT_GRADE + ") FROM " + TABLE_GRADES 
                    + " WHERE " + KEY_CATEGORY_ID 
                    + " = '" + catId +"'";  //catId is an int
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(q,null); 
            double d = c.getDouble(0);
```

Comment: Are there no records in the table. AVG() usually return NULL in that case (at least for other DBMSs, haven't tried with SQLite).

Comment: Try `if (c.moveToFirst()) { /* fetch the result */ } else { /* if 0 row returned */ }`

Comment: @Aprian I had forgotten to use `c.moveToFirst()`! Silly mistake. If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always `moveToFirst()` the cursor before accessing its content.

By doing so, there wouldn't be any problems even if the cursor returned 0 row.

Comment: One problem:  If there's 0 rows for the AVG and sqlite returns a row with null instead of a number, `c.getInt(0)` will happily return 0 instead of erroring, so you do have to check `c.isNull(0)` first.